# Coldfusion 9 Fusebox 4.1 ORM is not configured for the current application

Tags: orm, coldfusion, fusebox

When i load the specific page (dsp_sessions.cfm) the ORM works correctly, loading the information from my database and displays it in an html table. However, when i go to index.cfm, I get the error: ORM is not configured for the current application. I know that my circuits are setup correctly because the html  header displays, but the ORM commands don't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like wherever your dsp files are has the Application.cfc with the ORM config, not your root Application.cfc where index.cfm lives.

Comment: clearly i'm very new at this. i appreciate your response. however, all my files are in one directory (for the time being).

Comment: Can you post your Application.cfc code? (edit out anything sensitive of course)